# What is the SSL structure?

Tags: ssl, binary

Whenever I try different googling terms for the SSL protocol, I keep getting a load of pages explaining what SSL does, and the theory behind how it works.  How do I find out how the SSL format is structured digitally, bit for bit?

Comment: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtps5%2Fs5rcd.html

Comment: The normative reference is RFC 2246 and its successors.